# Another way to authenticate to VSTS without Internet Explorer popout?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

I developed a sync agent in Visual Studio 2012 that extracts data from Visual Studio Services (VSTS). I am using the libraries `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` and `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client`. The snippet code that i'm authenticating against VSTS is

```
 Uri collectionUri = new Uri(url);
 SimpleWebToken simpleWebToken = new SimpleWebToken(_password);
 NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(_user, _password);             
 TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri, networkCredential);
 teamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

where `url` is the url of VSTS. 
Is there some reason of why i execute the last line `teamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();` it prompts me an IE window for authenticate and ignores the user and password in the code?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that it failed to authenticate with the specified username and password, so it prompts the popup window for authentication again.

You can’t use mail account with that way to authenticate, you can create an **alternate authentication credential** for authentication (`https://{account}.visualstudio.com/_details/security/altcreds`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :)
Is there a way with that libraries use a personal token?

Comment: @lsalvatore I am using this package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/ and the code `VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "{personal access token}")); TfsTeamProjectCollection server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri, c);`